# Specific excel file only opens when connected to an external screen

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors

I have a user that cant open a specific excel file when it is not connected to an external screen but when i connect the laptop to a screen it opens directly.

So when the laptop is not connected to a screen, the excel loads as usual with the loading screen and then when it is done loading the program opens but you cant see the excel sheet. You can only see the program in the taskbar. I have to close the program via taskmanager, connect the laptop to a screen and open it again and the excel sheet pops up directly on the laptops monitor. When i disconnect the monitor with the excel file open it stays open on the laptop and can continue to work on it. Other colleagues that has access to this file does not have the same issue and they have the same laptop.

First line has tried this.

- Disable all external monitors.
- Enable them.
- Tried with both 100% windows scale and 150% windows scale
- Recreated office cache.
- Upgraded graphic drivers.

I cant seem to find anything about this problem online, i've tried every possible search word but no results. I suspect that it has something to do with the local profile but i couldn't try this method since the user had to work on the laptop, please let me know if there is anything else i can try before i book a time with the user so we can resolve this

Comment: I believe Excel uses the last used monitor by default, what happens if you move the opened document over to the monitor that is on, closing and re-opening?

Comment: Have you tried to run Excel in safe mode (excel /s) first and open this Excel file for a test?

Comment: @Crimsonfox

I will try this method when i meet the user and let you know if it worked. Thank you for the tip

Comment: @Emily

I will try this method when i meet the user and let you know if it worked. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I believe it does OPEN, but "off screen"... so:*

Windows and Linux:

If ANY window opens outside the current desktop
=> use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to access the window's 'Move' option.

**Check which keys to use with a visible window.**

On Ubuntu Linux I'd do;
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
... *(as 'Move' is the third option in the menu that appears for Alt+SPACE)*
then use the mouse to move the window ONTO the current desktop

*(mouse pointer won't move off desktop, so snaps the window to the closest desktop border)*.

Note also that any software that has a window open normally appears as you HOLD <kbd>Alt</kbd> and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, any more <kbd>TAB</kbd> while <kbd>Alt</kbd> is held down 'rotates' through the windows; let go of <kbd>Alt</kbd> to select that window.